# Pregunta sobre el siguiente algoritmo de Dijkstra en Python

Tags: python

Me surgió la duda de como modificar el código que se presenta más abajo para que solo muestre la ruta posible desde un nodo inicio y un nodo termino, en vez de que me compare las todas las rutas con un nodo inicio y todos los posibles nodos términos. Se trata del algoritmo de Dijkstra para el problema de la ruta más corta dada una matriz de adyacencia.

Sería de mucha ayuda si alguien me puede ayudar ya que es un problema que me ha tomado harto tiempo poder averiguar como resolver.

```
class Graph:

def minDistance(self, dist, queue):
    minimum = float("Inf")
    min_index = -1

    for i in range(len(dist)):
        if dist[i] < minimum and i in queue:
            minimum = dist[i]
            min_index = i
    return min_index

def printPath(self, parent, j):

    # Base Case : If j is source
    if parent[j] == -1:
        print (j),
        return
    self.printPath(parent, parent[j])
    print (j),

def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
    src = 0
    print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
    for i in range(1, len(dist)):
        print("\n%d --> %d \t\t%d \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])),
        self.printPath(parent, i)

def dijkstra(self, graph, src):

    row = len(graph)
    col = len(graph[0])

    dist = [float("Inf")] * row

    parent = [-1] * row

    dist[src] = 0

    queue = []
    for i in range(row):
        queue.append(i)

    while queue:
        u = self.minDistance(dist, queue)
        queue.remove(u)
        for i in range(col):
            if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
                if dist[u] + graph[u][i] < dist[i]:
                    dist[i] = dist[u] + graph[u][i]
                    parent[i] = u


    self.printSolution(dist, parent)

g = Graph()

g = Graph()

graph = [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
     [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0],
     [0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
     [0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6],
     [8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7],
     [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]]

g.dijkstra(graph, 0)
```

[image: Cuyo resultado que arroja es algo así]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que intentaste?

Comment: En el ejemplo, ¿cual sería la ruta posible que hay que mostrar? ¿Es la ruta con menor distancia?

Comment: Si la ruta mas corta según la matriz de adyacencia que se le ingrese y el nodo inicio