# Problema con Python, pasar código de la versión Python2 a la versión Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, lambda, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo un problema, estoy iniciando a programar en lenguaje Python y tengo un inconveniente con un proyecto de la universidad que me han asignado y en dicho proyecto tengo que hacer uso del algoritmo de Dijkstra para encontrar el camino mas corto en una matriz ortogonal formada por grafos/nodos, he estado investigando estos últimos días y me tope con el algoritmo en internet, la verdad ya lo he leído varias veces y masomenos logro descifrar como funciona, el problema esta en que este algoritmo por lo que llegue a ver fue creado en Python2 y actualmente yo necesito crear mi algoritmo pero en la versión de Python3, ya le di muchas vueltas y la verdad quisiera saber si alguien me podría apoyar en detallarme como sería (no se si llamarle traducción de Python2 a Python3)

El código es el siguiente

```
class Grafo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.relaciones = {}
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.relaciones)
class Arista(object):
    def __init__(self, elemento, peso):
        self.elemento = elemento
        self.peso = peso       
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.elemento) + str(self.peso)
 
def agregar(grafo, elemento):
    grafo.relaciones.update({elemento:[]})
def relacionar(grafo, elemento1, elemento2, peso = 1):
    relacionarUnilateral(grafo, elemento1, elemento2, peso)
    relacionarUnilateral(grafo, elemento2, elemento1, peso)
   
def relacionarUnilateral(grafo, origen, destino, peso):
    grafo.relaciones[origen].append(Arista(destino, peso))
def caminoMinimo(grafo, origen, destino):
    etiquetas = {origen:(0,None)}
    dijkstra(grafo, destino, etiquetas, [])
    return construirCamino(etiquetas, origen, destino)
def construirCamino(etiquetas, origen, destino):
    print origen, destino
    if origen == destino:
        return [origen]
    return construirCamino(etiquetas, origen, anterior(etiquetas[destino])) + [destino]
   
   
def dijkstra(grafo, destino, etiquetas, procesados):
    nodoActual = menorValorNoProcesado(etiquetas, procesados)
    if nodoActual == destino:
        return
    procesados.append(nodoActual)
    for vecino in vecinoNoProcesado(grafo, nodoActual, procesados):
        generarEtiqueta(grafo, vecino, nodoActual, etiquetas)
    dijkstra(grafo, destino, etiquetas, procesados)
def generarEtiqueta(grafo, nodo, anterior, etiquetas):
    etiquetaNodoAnterior = etiquetas[anterior]
    etiquetaPropuesta = peso(grafo, anterior, nodo) + acumulado(etiquetaNodoAnterior),anterior
    if (not(etiquetas.has_key(nodo)) or  acumulado(etiquetaPropuesta) < acumulado(etiquetas[nodo]) ):
        etiquetas.update({nodo:etiquetaPropuesta})
def aristas(grafo, nodo):
    return grafo.relaciones[nodo]
       
def vecinoNoProcesado(grafo, nodo, procesados):
    aristasDeVecinosNoProcesados = filter(lambda x: not x in procesados, aristas(grafo,nodo))
    return [arista.elemento for arista in aristasDeVecinosNoProcesados]
def peso(grafo, nodoOrigen, nodoDestino):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x if x.elemento == nodoDestino else y, grafo.relaciones[nodoOrigen]).peso
def acumulado(etiqueta):
    return etiqueta[0]
def anterior(etiqueta):
    return etiqueta[1]
          
def menorValorNoProcesado(etiquetas, procesados):
    etiquetadosSinProcesar = filter(lambda (nodo,_):not nodo in procesados, etiquetas.iteritems())
    return min(etiquetadosSinProcesar, key=lambda (_, (acum, __)): acum)[0]
```

En realidad en donde tengo mas dudas es en esas funciones donde se hace uso la función lambda, ya que no logre entender muy bien que hacen y de ahí que no puedo acoplar esto a mi proyecto.

Agradecería mucho si alguien me apoyara igual muchisimas gracias por su atención, igualmente seguiré trabajando en ello para ver si llego a una solución también.

Comment: Las funciones lambda son funciones anónimas, en esa parte no veo que debas cambiar algo

Comment: Tengo otra duda en la penúltima lineal hay un `lambda (nodo, _ )` ahí se interpreta como si estuviera recibiendo dos parámetros la función o solamente uno. Digo esto porque según se, una función lambda solo puede recibir un parámetro.

Comment: las funciones lambda pueden recibir varios parámetros, recuerda que la sintaxis es `lambda <parámetros>: <operación>`

Comment: para python 3 no es necesario heredar de object (no hay problema si lo haces, pero por defecto python ya lo hace) y la sintaxis del `print` cambió a `print()`. Si tu código hace cosas concretas y no usas *trucos* extraños no hay mucho que cambiar (aparentemente)

Comment: ahora si yo uso esta sintaxis de aquí  `(nodo, _ )` me sale el siguiente error `Sublist parameters are not supported in Python 3.xPylance` y es que yo entiendo que esta sintaxis ya no es válida para Python3, ahora bien mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los valores de ese diccionario (creo que así se llama perdón si me equivoco) llamado etiquetas entonces?

Comment: por cierto las lambda no llevan paréntesis :)

Comment: Es probable que ese código haya que reescribirlo desde 0. Como no manejo el tema y ya existen referencias en el sitio, ¿te sirve alguna de [Estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+dijkstra)? En todo caso, haciendo una [búsqueda más general](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dijkstra), o [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teor%c3%ada-de-grafos) y que involucra otros lenguajes.

Comment: Hay varias preguntas sobre DIjkstra (en Python y otros lenguajes) en este sitio, que muestran la implementación en Python 3. Deberias leer esos primero. Por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398301/pregunta-sobre-el-siguiente-algoritmo-de-dijkstra-en-python

Comment: Gracias por los consejos indagare mas acerca en los links proporcionados ya que me había cerrado únicamente a esté código, gracias por su apoyo y tiempo a todos.